# IllegalAccessError in JsonTemplateLayout in log4j2

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, jsontemplate

Error : -
[![IllegalAccessError][1]][1]

Log4j2.xml :-

[![Log4j2 configuration][2]][2]

Maven dependencies :-

[![pom.xml][3]][3]

Code :-

[![Controller class][4]][4]

TIA
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvEQv.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhLEu.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/99aWb.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x62a2.png

Comment: please use text instead of images in your question. You probably have a library version mismatch: can you run `mvn dependency:list` and add the result (as text) to your question)?

Comment: Thanks @PiotrP.Karwasz , I am actually getting these errors in VM , so I am unable to copy paste here and cant login inside vm . So please bare with images , I am adding the list , Please Check .

Comment: Got the same issue, created a thread here https://stackoverflow.com/q/74783286/8439424