# IllegalAccessError after updating log4j JSONTemplateLayout package

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I am running a Spring boot application on java-17-openjdk. I use the log4j-layout-template-json package to output json logs to stdout.

Everything has been working fine until I updated the package version from 2.17.2 to 2.18.0, now I get these stack traces every time the app attempts to log something:

```
2022-12-13 10:28:59,028 main ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender Console org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout$StringBuilderEncoder tried to access method 'void org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.TextEncoderHelper.encodeText(java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder, java.nio.CharBuffer, java.nio.ByteBuffer, java.lang.StringBuilder, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.ByteBufferDestination)' (org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout$StringBuilderEncoder and org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.TextEncoderHelper are in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @76fb509a)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:165)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:616)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:552)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1994)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1852)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.log(LogAdapter.java:270)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.info(LogAdapter.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarting(StartupInfoLogger.java:55)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.logStartupInfo(SpringApplication.java:618)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:377)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at org.engine.App.main(App.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout$StringBuilderEncoder tried to access method 'void org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.TextEncoderHelper.encodeText(java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder, java.nio.CharBuffer, java.nio.ByteBuffer, java.lang.StringBuilder, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.ByteBufferDestination)' (org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout$StringBuilderEncoder and org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.TextEncoderHelper are in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @76fb509a)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout$StringBuilderEncoder.encode(JsonTemplateLayout.java:241)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout$StringBuilderEncoder.encode(JsonTemplateLayout.java:216)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout.encode(JsonTemplateLayout.java:304)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.layout.template.json.JsonTemplateLayout.encode(JsonTemplateLayout.java:58)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:215)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:208)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:199)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    ... 31 more
```

As one can see, the problem already occurs for logs made by spring itself. Updating log4j-layout-template-json to the latest version (2.19.0) did not fix the problem.

Note that this only appears when trying to execute the jar file of the app but not when running surefire and failsafe tests with maven and spring-mvc.

For more details on my version of java:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.5 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.5+8-Ubuntu-2ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.5+8-Ubuntu-2ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Here is a sample of my pom.xml file:

```xml
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-layout-template-json</artifactId>
      <version>2.18.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

My log4j config file is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <JsonTemplateLayout eventTemplateUri="classpath:JSONLogLayout.json"></JsonTemplateLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>

        <logger name="org.jooq" level="warn" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        </logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>

    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: This seems related but did not get an answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/73432624/8439424

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spring-boot-starter-parent` POM files manages the version of hundreds of library versions (cf. its parent [`spring-boot-dependencies`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies), where the `<dependencyManagement>` occurs). All Log4j2 artifacts are among them.

Even if `log4j-layout-template-json:2.18.0` has a dependency on `log4j-core:2.18.0`, Maven will select version `2.17.2` of the latter and cause the version problem you are experiencing.

In order for all Log4j2 artifacts to have the same version, you need to override the `log4j2.version` property specified in `spring-boot-dependencies`:

```xml
<properties>
    <log4j2.version>2.19.0</log4j2.version>
</properties>
```

and **remove** explicit versions from your POM file.